# How can I use a RegEx to extract potential email addresses and spacing from a comma-separated string

Tags: regex

Given the following string (leading and trailing quotes provided to highlight leading/trailing whitespace):

```
"  foo@bar.com  , baz@acme, bill@bing.co.uk ,inv liad , thing  "
```

Is it possible to use a regular expression to extract both (potential) email addresses and the groups of characters separating them?  Ideally the matches would be:

```
"  "
"foo@bar.com"
"  , "
"baz@acme"
", "
"bill@bing.co.uk"
", "
"inv liad"
" , "
"thing"
"  "
```

I'm hoping that the regex can make use of named groups to allow me to differentiate between potential emails and inter-email spacing.  I don't want to validate emails in this step, or use code to split and trim.  I need a list of *potential* matches and their match ranges.  A further step will perform the validation and apply colour highlighting to a text field.

EDIT: Knowing the positions of the inter-email groups is not a strict requirement since I'm only validating and highlighting the potential emails.

I'm using Xamarin.iOS so have access to both C# and Swift/ObjC RE engines.  TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a (relatively) simple alternation with negative lookahead, and explicit capture of the potential email, in c#, might look like:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
string text = "  foo@bar.com  , baz@acme, bill@bing.co.uk ,inv liad , thing , ";
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture;

string pattern = @"
    # Match space at the start of the line, at the end, and around commas
    ^\s+ | \s*,\s* | \s+$

    # ...Or...
    |

    # Match anything not followed by a space-surounded comma
    (?<email>
        ((?!
            \s*,\s* | \s+$
        ).)
    *)";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern, options);

foreach (Match m in matches) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Groups["email"].Value)) {
        Console.WriteLine($"({m.Index}, {m.Length}) |{m.Value}|");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
(2, 11) |foo@bar.com|
(17, 8) |baz@acme|
(27, 15) |bill@bing.co.uk|
(44, 8) |inv liad|
(55, 5) |thing|
```

Answer (score 0):

Using C#, you could do something like

```
string[] result = Regex.Split(
    "  foo@bar.com  , baz@acme, bill@bing.co.uk ,inv liad , thing  ",
    @"(\b[^,]+\b)"
);
```

The regex matches any part that, in your words, is a potential email address. Splitting on that while capturing it (the surrounding `()`) inserts the items matched as separate elements.

The match explained:

```
\b      A word boundary
[^,]+   Any number of, but at least one, characters that isn't a comma.
\b      Another word baoundary
```

See it here at [Regex Storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5Cb%5B%5E%2C%5D%2B%5Cb%29&i=%20%20foo%40bar.com%20%20%2C%20baz%40acme%2C%20bill%40bing.co.uk%20%2Cinv%20liad%20%2C%20thing%20%20&o=s)
See it here at [ideone](https://ideone.com/Vb5JkW).

---

**Edit**

Adjusted according to comment (the question stated the positions wasn't required ;)
Do matches with `\b[^,]+\b|[ ,]+`.

[Here at ideone](https://ideone.com/P0GC86).

Output

```
(0, 2) |  |
(2, 11) |foo@bar.com|
(13, 4) |  , |
(17, 8) |baz@acme|
(25, 2) |, |
(27, 15) |bill@bing.co.uk|
(42, 2) | ,|
(44, 8) |inv liad|
(52, 3) | , |
(55, 5) |thing|
(60, 2) |  |
```

An **illustration** using JS:

```js
var sInput = '  foo@bar.com  , baz@acme, bill@bing.co.uk ,inv liad , thing  ',
    re = /\b[^,]+\b|[ ,]+/g,
    m;

while ((m = re.exec(sInput)) !== null) {

  console.log(`(${m.index},${re.lastIndex-m.index}) |${m[0]}|`);
}
```

Comment: This is a lot less RE syntax soup than my answer (and taught me something I didn't know in `re.Split()`, as well as `ideone` - thanks!) but doesn't provide match indices (required to highlight the text field after validation) or differentiate between email matches and spacing ones.